# Sending asynchronous message Pusher HTTP API for PHP

Tags: php, asynchronous, pusher

I have messages being sent with [pusher-http-php](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php) inside a `for` loop. The `$pusher->trigger` call waits for a return to go on. The loop takes 2-3 seconds without the Pusher messages. With the `trigger` call, it causes a 504 error and it takes over half an hour in the database.
Is there a way to send these messages asynchronously in PHP?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that [the `$pusher->trigger` method](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php#publishingtriggering-events) makes a synchronous HTTP request to Pusher. You could use [`$pusher->triggerBatch`](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php#batches) to cut down on the network latency.

If you really want to make `$pusher->trigger` asynchronous, you could wrap it in an asynchronous task. [Here's an introduction to async PHP](https://www.phproundtable.com/episode/asynchronous-php).